ms-gamingoverlay with tweaked GameBarless Windows 11
I opted to completely omit the XBox Game Bar bloatware before installing Windows 11.
So now, whenever I connect an Xinput controller to use with Valve's Steam, I get the annoying pop-up prompting

I used an autounattend.xml file to prevent Windows 11 from installing the common "bloatware" suite that comes with Microsoft's OOBE solution for home users.

There is a solution to this problem but only if your tell us how you removed the application

I used an autounattend.xml file to prevent Windows 11 from installing the common "bloatware" suite that comes with Microsoft's OOBE solution for home users.

Please add, to the question itself and not in a comment down here, the details of the unattend file you used. THAT is the detail we need.
